# How can I determine who sent an inbox message to me on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

The inbox message has a yellow/tan box below it that says "To reply to this message, follow the link below."  Then there are a lot of numbers and letters which have no meaning to me.

Comment: first off, stop shouting at people who are not obliged to care about you or your problem

Answer (score 4):

The sender should be shown at the top of the message.  If this is missing then it is probably a fake notification email which is intended to look like it came from Facebook; they probably want you to click on the link and maybe enter your Facebook login and password on their fake site.  Obviously you should not do that.